# Identification of a plug

Tags: identification, plug, socket

I found this cable in a box of old bits. It is 4 wire and has test clips on one end and a barrel type plug on the other.

I am trying to find out what the plug is called and I hope to locate a corresponding socket.

[image: Conical Plug]

The plug is about 40mm long and 9mm wide at the upper conductor.

The other end:
[image: Test Clips]

Comment: Well, that's unique looking. Like someone designed a fix for standard TRS jacks shorting while inserting. The other side of the cable would be good to see too.

Comment: Some searching showed that it looks more like a Tiny Telephone connector called a Bantam plug, but all my google image searches only show 2 and 3 conductor versions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)